# How config github action to deploy app when i need to enter two passphrase (my gateway and my instance)

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions

I have a docker app in my instance (ubuntu) and would like to create a workflow in github action to automate the deployment, for example, git pull, and execute the docker compose, etc.

The problem:

To get into my instance (where I have the app), I need to go through a gateway and enter my passphrase, then enter my instance's passphrase.

I use this command:

`ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i /user/.ssh/gateway/gateway.pem -W %h:%p ubuntu@ip-gateway" -i /user/.ssh/instance/instance.pem ubuntu@ip-instance`

How can I apply this in Github Actions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create GitHub secret variable from `settings/secrets/actions/New repository secret` from your repository.

And use it in your workflow like

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3 
      - name: Deploy in EC2
        env:
            GATEWAYPEM: ${{ secrets.GATEWAYPEM  }}
            GATEWAYIP : ${{ secrets.GATEWAYIP  }}
            INSTANCEPEM : ${{ secrets.INSTANCEPEM  }}
            INSTANCEIP : ${{ secrets.INSTANCEIP  }}
        run: |
          echo "$GATEWAYPEM" > gatewaypem.pem && chmod 400 gatewaypem.pem
          echo "$INSTANCEPEM" > instancepem.pem && chmod 400 instancepem.pem
          ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ./gatewaypem.pem -W %h:%p ubuntu@${GATEWAYIP}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ./instancepem.pem ubuntu@${INSTANCEIP}
```

Comment: And how can I set it the paraphrase for each .pem?

Comment: Github secret variable is the secure way to store sensitive information so no need to paraphrase.

Comment: You can just open your `.pem` file on your terminal, and copy and paste file content in the value textbox.